# Show ManyToManyField attributes of a given model in template

Tags: django, django-templates

How can I show in a template the attributes related by a ManyToManyField of a model?

**models.py**

```
class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    user = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='user_group')

class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    group = models.ManyToManyField(Group, related_name='group_team')
```

**views.py**

```
class Index(ListView):
    template_name = 'App/index.html'
    model = User

    def get_queryset(self):
        return User.objects.filter(...)
```

**template**

```
{% for user in user_list %}
    {{ user.username }}
    {{ user.user_group.name }}
    {{ user.user_group.group_team.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

I can show the username of the user but not the rest of the fields.

Answer (score 2):

Since a ManyToMany relationship may have *many* objects all I had to do is iterate over them:

```
{% for group in user.user_group.all %}
    {{ group.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

**Update**: As Todor suggests adding [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.prefetch_related) avoid unnecessary database queries

```
User.objects.filter(...).prefetch_related('user_group')
```

Comment: In your `get_queryset` prefetch `user_groups` by:  `User.objects.filter(...).prefetch_related('user_group')`, this way you wont make 1 query per user to get all his groups.